# list-style-image svg smaller in webkit

Tags: css, svg

I've got a bit of an odd problem with my svg list-style-image in google chrome.

```
.services ul {
list-style-image: url('images/check.svg');
list-style-position: inside;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

The image size is supposed to be 16px x 16px. But it appears way smaller, about half of the size. If I switch to png, the size is correct. In other browsers it seems allright.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

since you are calling the SVG image; you have to define SVG on your page as well. It is also mandatory  to define the `height` and `width` as well in your SVG otherwise by default its take `1em` width and height if not mentioned.

```
<svg height="16px" width="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16"  version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
</svg>
```

It would be better way to call the image by using `background:url` this way a `height` and `width` can given to image, so the `SVG image` could rendered properly.

```
.services li:before { 
content:''; 
display:inline-block; 
height:1em; 
width:1em; 
background-image:url('images/check.svg'); 
background-size:contain; 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
padding-left: 2em; 
}
```

Comment: I'd like to call the SVG from CSS without having to add svg code into my html. I did the same for a background image without any problems.

Comment: @Jando you must define the width and height property as well in your `class`. let me know by adding `width` and `height` works for you.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. Setting the width and height for list-style-image isn't possible so I found out about this work around:
.services li:before {
 content:'';
 display:inline-block;
 height:1em;
 width:1em;
 background-image:url('images/check.svg');
 background-size:contain;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding-left: 2em;
}

Comment: Glad someway I can help you. :) let me update the answer so any third person can benefited.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, especially with the size on iOs devices. I solved it by using a :before attribute

```
.services ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.usp ul li:before {
    content: url('images/check.svg');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's an `;` missing after `url('images/check.svg')`?

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to have list symbols, that don't disturb the floating of the list items, take this code: (SASS)

```
ul
    list-style: none

li
    margin: 1.5rem 0
    position: relative

li:before
    content: " "
    background-size: cover
    background-image: url("img/check.png")
    width: 1.5rem
    height: 1.5rem
    position: absolute
    left: -2rem
```