# How to Replace the Web Font with SVG icon in CSS(Font Awesome)?

Tags: css, svg, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I notice that in my CSS file, there are some rules which uses Font Awesome Web font, as below:

```
ul.fancy li:before, .category-page ul li:before {
    display: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f0da";
}
```

Now I want to replace it with SVG icon or SVG Sprites from Font Awesome. Since Fontawesome icon allows to be used in both Web Font or SVG icon, its CSS Pseudo-elements should also support all these methods too. Just wonder how to do so? I check the Font Awesome website and cannot find the corresponding document on such a case.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179094/list-style-image-svg-smaller-in-webkit/22179481

Comment: I'm not quite clear, are you saying that you don't want to show the Fontawesome icon but instead you want to show your own SVG?

Comment: @AHaworth, Sorry for confusion. I do want to show Fontawesome icon, but don't use the Web font method since that means I need to include and download the web font file together with my web pages. I want to use individual SVG icon or SVG Sprites from Fontawesome to improve performance. Since Fontawesome icon allows to be used in both Web Font or SVG icon, its CSS Pseudo-elements should also support all these methods too, though I not find the info in their documents.

Answer (score 0):

Web fonts were really a great idea and a very useful one for you to have responsive un styled icons for web development. But right now it's not that too much good idea since every major browser supports the svg standard it makes no sense to install, or call via CDN a web font which is consuming resources for you to use, how many, ten icons on your app or web site?
So, for example, the last version of font awesome comes with a src folder in which there are all the icons on svg format.
Said that, there is another easy way for you to grab the icon from within the font and turn it into a svg. Let's say you have installed the font to your system. Then you download the cheat sheet of the font and open it on the browser, look for the selectable version of the icon you want and select it and copy. Then you open Inkscape and get the text tool and paste the selected icon. Look in the font selector for the font and apply it to the icon you just copied as text. Then convert the text into a path and save it as svg.

The next step is to create a css system to place the icons instead of the font icons. As long as I have done you should be able to use the system that was created in the framework for the use of font awasome. Just open the font css and look for the general stiling, I mean, the classes `i, icon`, mainly and paste them into your css file.

Now you try this, replace the font in the code that you provide with a background and the url of your icon.

Of course, it will be useful just for one icon
If you want more you should create yourself a similar system like the one the css of the font uses.
In my case I have created a class prefix **simbicon-xxxx** where the xxx stands for the name of the icon. I will show you now.

CSS

```
.simbicon-logout {background: url('../img/logout.svg') center no-repeat;bottom: 0;width: 36px;height: 36px;}
```

HTML

```
 <i class="icon simbicon-logout"></i>
```

And the few icons that I actually use on the proyect get displayed exactly as the font icons did.
One caveat of this method is that the font icons comes with no fill attribute so they get the custom color of the theme. With this system you have to place a fill inside each svg icon.

Notice that the **"\f0da";** in your css refers to the specific icon to be displayed from the font. In the cheat sheet appears an image of the icon, this code above and a selectable icon. That last is the one you need to select to copy as text inside Inkscape.

[image]

In the image above are shown the css class of the icon, the acssi reference and the selectable which is inside the red circle.

Sorry for the typos but I am on my mobile now and I have no glasses here.