# Load SVG icons from site folder or use FontAwesome

Tags: performance, icons, font-awesome, pagespeed

I am trying to reduce page load time. Now it's turn for icons.

What is better for page speed?

1. Load 10-50 SVG icons from files or
2. Use FontAwesome

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is reduce page load times you surely better use svg icons served from a local folder in your server. How many icons you will use? 50? My biggest project used 34 icons half of which were not present in any icon font, so I had to draw them myself, after that I realized, one day I commited a typo when coding and Font Awesome didn't load. And my page loaded really fast. Nothing else to think about it. I have created a personal system which essence is explained here [How to Replace the Web Font with SVG icon in CSS(Font Awesome)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765863/how-to-replace-the-web-font-with-svg-icon-in-cssfont-awesome/68766858#68766858)
Hope it hepls you as much as it has to me!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've found an online app called IcoMoon. If I understand correctly, it allowes me to pick  icons I need one by one and use them as a font.

Comment: You need to install and load the font anyway. At least it was true the last time I heard about Icon Moon.